# In the Made in Abyss manga, why does Bondrewd sometimes refer to Prushka with the formal "anata" and sometimes with the intimate "kimi"?

Tags: japanese-language, made-in-abyss

I was looking through some raws and I noticed that Bondrewd consistently uses "kimi" when talking to others, but there are a few cases where he uses "anata" with Prushka. Looking through more raws, I also noticed that he used "kimi" in the beginning, but changed to "anata" later. What does this mean?

Comment: Sounds like the relationship between them changed in some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the context of when the words were used. Kimi is considered more familiar than anata, but depending on context, there are several different connotations:

1. A leader might use it to a subordinate, especially when asserting authority
2. When the two people are not emotionally close, and it is not a leader to subordinate situation, then it is considered rude or condescending
3. Two people who are quite close may use it as a closer way of addressing each other, sort of like calling your friends, "pal" or "bro." I think this connotation might be reserved for use between peers, like friends or lovers, but I'm not sure on that.

Kimi is also considered more masculine speech, though I have heard women in anime use it on occasion. Anata, meanwhile, is a more neutral way of saying "you".

Given its Bondrewd to Prushka, I think his use of kimi is more likely to be him being condescending or ordering her around. He may have then switched to anata when he felt like being more polite, or having the appearance of being more polite.  She is his adopted daughter, so he might say anata sometimes when he wants to appear nice. His use of kimi to everyone else is almost certainly as leader to subordinate, or just to generally be condescending.